# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|\.)dt(\.|$)/: Stack overflow error in yajra datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable

When I am reinitializing yajra datatable I am getting this error 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^|.)dt(.|$)/: Stack overflow

What could be its possible reason.

Comment: It might have something to do with this, but can you be a bit more specific in what happens when and where? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex

Answer (score 0):

if the regex is indeed `/(^|.)dt(.|$)/:` then the trailing `:` is no good in javascript the regex should both start and end with `/`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

The only allowed options are **g m i u y** (after the last `/`):
 https://regex101.com/r/l7mwwt/1

```js
const regex = /(^|.)dt(.|$)\/:/gmiuy;
const str = ``;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

[image]

If you, by any chance, wanted to match `/:` litteral you should escape your slash